# Casting Numpy array to np.int_ throws RuntimeWarning after multiple repetitions

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I came across a weird behavior with `numpy`, for which I do not have a good explanation.
In one function, I do some operations on a copied `numpy` array. There is no issue when I run this code once. However, when I call the function with the same input in a for loop as example I get the following error:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast histogram 
= ((histogram / histogram.sum()) * INT_CASTER).astype(np.int64)
```

The `histogram` is a *m x m* shaped `ndarray` with `np.float64` as the dtype. `histograms` is a n x m x m tensor, containing all individual histograms. Each `histogram` sums to > 0, so division by 0 error would be quite weird.
These histograms are generated each function call from external data. I am not sure how to avoid this behavior. I also tried `del histograms` as a way to maybe avoid this error. This only helped partially, where I can now call the function a few times consecutively without getting the error, however with more than 5 calls this error appears again. Without the `del` the error appears after two iterations already.

The function is as follows:

```py
def _normalize_cast_int(histograms: NDArray[np.float64]) -> NDArray[np.int64]:
    int_histograms = np.empty(histograms.shape, dtype=np.int64)

    instances = histograms.shape[0]
    for i in range(instances):
        histogram = histograms[i].copy()
        histogram = ((histogram / histogram.sum()) * INT_CASTER).astype(np.int64)

        error = INT_CASTER - histogram.sum()
        mask = np.zeros(shape=histogram.size, dtype=np.int64)
        mask[:error] += 1
        np.random.seed(42)
        np.random.shuffle(mask)
        int_histograms[i] = histogram + np.reshape(mask, (-1, histogram.shape[0]))

    return int_histograms
```

Comment: If the sum were 0, you'd end up with NaNs, which cannot be cast to integers.

Comment: The sum should never change, since i generate the histograms n times from the same data. The data itself is not changed, so a sum that is 0 should not be possible.

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added the function, the input NDArray can be any shape. The important part is the conversion from float to int. And the input to this function does NOT change for n iterations, but the outcome still seems to be different.

Comment: And you're sure that no ROW of the histogram sums to 0?

Comment: An individual row can sum to 0. But the histogram itself can never sum to 0. Since I use sum() without a specified axis, I assumed this will not break anything, since the actual returned value > 0.

Also the weird thing is that this operation works perfectly for n tries and breaks after n+1 tries. (n is 5 most times).

Comment: you can catch the error and print something like this for debugging `array_with_potential_nans.isna().sum()` if this is greater zero... then there are nans in your array. And, even better, provide a copy to paste example of your problem that is reproducable

Comment: *"An individual row can sum to 0."* You have `histogram = histograms[i].copy()`, so `histogram` will be a row of `histograms`.  Then `histogram / histogram.sum()` will result in 0/0 when a row of `histograms` sums to 0 .

Comment: I should have clarified a bit more. the histograms variable is of shape n x m x m. It is essentially a tensor of multiple histograms stacked together. each individual histogram cant sum to 0.